# Get dependent type of variadic template parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

Let's say I have:

```
struct M1 { static constexpr int T = 3; }
struct M2 { static constexpr int T = 8; }
struct M3 { static constexpr int T = 19; }
```

This is really two linked questions:

1. What is the best way of storing a list of all M types such that later on I won't have to repeat myself?

in fantasy-c++: `using AllMs = <M1, M2, M3>;`

2. Given that list, how do I get a list of M::T (but as types)?

in fantasy-c++: `using AllMTs = AllMs::T ...;` (maybe using std::integral_type)

---

For instance, I can multiply inherit from all O like so:

```
template <class... M> class K: public O<M>... { }

template <typename ...P> struct ParameterPackApplicator {
    template <template <typename...> typename T> using apply = T<P...>;
};

using AllM = ParameterPackApplicator<M1, M2, M3>;

using MultiplyInheritedThing = AllM::apply<K>;
```

... but I can't seem to figure out how to get a typelist of all M::T...

Comment: what do you mean with "I wont have to repeat myself" ? What repetition do you want to avoid?

Comment: also 2. is not quite clear what is `M::T`?

Comment: What is `T` actually? A variable, type or function?

Comment: I want to multiply inherit something later: class S: public O<AllMs>. And get these dependent types. And other things...

Comment: why do you want to inherit? Those type have only a static member which has the same name in all of them

Comment: assume M1, M2, M3 will also have other stuff in them

Comment: you can make `M{i}` inherit from `M{i-1}` then you can do `class S : public M3 {}`

Comment: assume I dont know what you are planning to do ;)

Comment: @Timo sorry, clarified (int)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Um... does it matter?

Comment: Can you go into more detail on your use case? There are a lot of different approaches in that area (if I guess the direction of this topic right). There is inheritance, tuples, fold expressions, the visitor pattern and so on. Depending on what you're trying to achieve one is better than the other or might not work at all.

Comment: @Timo Well I guess I have several use cases, but the common thing is that I don't want to repeat <M1, M2, M3> anywhere - just once.

Comment: If you really want just that, use tuple like the answers below suggest. But that approach seems flawed imo.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create an alias to a pack in C++. Template pack expension must be done in the same context as the pack is introduced.

However, you can put it in a tuple then unpack it later:

```
using AllMs = std::tuple<M1, M2, M3>;
```

Then use an index sequence to unpack it:

```
template<typename = std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<AllMTs>>>
struct MyType;

template<std::size_t... S>
struct MyType<std::index_sequence<S...>> : std::tuple_element_t<S, AllMTs>... {};
```

Of course for you use case it's not a that good trade off. You would be better off inheriting from a single class that directly has the pack and deal with it instead:

```
template<typename... AllMs>
struct Inheritance : AllMs... {
    // can do `AllMs::T...` to get all ints
};


struct MyType : Inheritance<M1, M2, M3> {

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but you can use variadic templates in combination with a tuple:

```
#include <tuple>

struct M1 { int x = 0; };
struct M2 { int y = 0; };

using allM = std::tuple<M1,M2>;

template <typename ... X>
struct foo : public X... {};

template <typename ...X>
struct foo<std::tuple<X...>> : public X... {};

int main() {
    foo<allM> x;
    x.x = x.y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can't actually do AllMs::T... as Guillaume proposes. Or at least I couldn't get the right syntax... the below works for me though.

```
template <typename... P> struct parameter_pack {
    template <template <typename...> typename T> using apply = T<P...>;
};

template <typename... P>
struct TGetter {
    using Ts = std::integer_sequence<int, P::T...>;
};

using AllTypes = parameter_pack<M1, M2, M3>;

using AllTs = AllTypes::apply<TGetter>::Ts;
```